# application_start Event to pre-load objects in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Does spring (spring mvc) have an event that gets fired once, on application startup, where I can hook in and load some objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use the normal initialization mechanisms  of a singleton bean, e.g. [`@PostConstruct` or `InitializingBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle)? A singleton bean will only be created/initialized once at context startup.

Alternatively, you can implement the [`Lifecycle` interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-processor), which gets callbacks from Spring when the context itself start up or shuts down, rather than the bean itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to refresh your application context, you can simply listen to

org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent